# Libxl library not found

Tags: ios5

I want export the sqlite into the xls file.How it can be export to xls file? 
Anyone knows that please tell me..
its argent requirment
if any one having code please insert link

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here : https://github.com/andreac/RSSheet

Comment: Awesome, its work in my project but the difficulty is that how to add the data new cell and row? It will show only in one recent data not other data. Please help me out from this.

Comment: look here for example: http://www.devapp.it/wordpress/rssheet-una-classe-alpha-per-scrivere-fogli-di-calcolo-con-le-nostre-applicazioni-iphone-e-ipad.html

Comment: This is code i use.

    RSworkSheetRow * row2 = [[RSworkSheetRow alloc] initWithHeight:25];
    [row2 addCellString:content];
    [row2 addCellString: stringData];
    [sheet addWorkSheetRow:row2];    
    [folder addWorkSheet:sheet];

I take string as content and sringData, it take different data from that i want to store that data in new row. Now it store only one data the last one not store previous data.

Like

    Name    Address
   Joliy      north road

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: for each row you need to create an object RSworkSheetRow, vai where to insert the text of each cell addCellString. and then add it to your sheet.

Comment: Can we add image in that RSSheet? I want add image also in the excel sheet.Its just for identification of name and address. is it possible to add image? Please tell me about that